# Nginx multi-domain and multi-app with tomcat usage

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I am trying to use one nignx server to proxy multi-app running in tomcat:

```
a.example.com ->192.168.1.101:8080/ps and 192.168.1.102:8080/ps
b.example.com ->192.168.1.102:9080/ir
```

Here is my nginx.conf.It seems not work.Please help me.Thanks

```
upstream ps {
    server 192.168.1.101:8080 weight=2;
    server 192.168.1.102:8080 weight=3;
    }

  upstream ir {
        server 192.168.1.102:9080;
    }
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  a.example.com;
        location /{
        proxy_pass http://ps/ps;
        }
    }
    server{
        listen  80;
        server_name b.example.com;
        location /{
            proxy_pass http://ir/ir;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Probably you missed trailing slash in proxy_pass.

Comment: problecm is : a.example.com only proxyed to 192.168.1.101:8080,but not to ps    app

Comment: It should with this config. How did you check that?

Comment: This config does not work.
I think 'proxy_pass http://ps/ps;' is wrong. It should write like this 'proxy_pass http://ps;'.And the tomcat set the app as default.Then all is OK.I just do not like this way.

Comment: Have you tried to add trailing slash? In your current config request to `a.example.com/test/path` will be proxied to `192.168.1.101:8080/pstest/path`. I'm quite sure thats not what you want.

Comment: I am a newer on nginx.Now it works on the demand that setting the tomcat with a default app docBase config.I will thy the 'trailing slash' config and give u a respone . : )

Comment: OK.It is not what I want.People have to type full path to access website this way.

Comment: I don't understand you last comment. Could you explain what you want to see in browser address bar and where it should be proxied with some examples.

Comment: The url in browser address bar should be 'a.example.com/ps' to access '192.168.1.101:8080/ps',not 'a.example.com' expected